# Why this IF jquery statement is not working?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I would like to ask what is wrong with this code? I can't get it to work..The goal is to change element's height when element.width is below 400px.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".top-container").width <= 400) {
    $(".top-container").height = 20;
  } else {
    $(".top-container").height = 40;
  }
})
```

Comment: These are functions so correct usage is get `width()` and set `height(40)`

Comment: width() and height() are functions mate

Comment: RTM: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: Voted to close: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: It's **well-worth** your time to read the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two, and it repays you that time almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Because jQuery objects don't have numeric `width` and `height` properties. Their [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) properties are functions you need to call:

```
if ($(".top-container").width() <= 400)
// --------------------------^^
```

Similarly, to set width or height, you call the function passing in a value:

```
$(".top-container").height(40);
```

---

Side note: It's frequently best to avoid repeatedly re-querying the DOM. Do it once, then reuse the result:

```
var topContainer = $(".top-container");
if (topContainer.width() <= 400) {
    topContainer.height(20);
} else {
    topContainer.height(40);
}
```

You can also the conditional operator:

```
var topContainer = $(".top-container");
topContainer.height(topContainer.width() <= 400 ? 20 : 40);
```

Comment: @mplungjan: Already have done. :-) I mean, it's not a typo, but we'll go with "unreproducible" on the basis that if you look at jQuery for any length of time...